# jdbc-odbc bridge - import text with german umlauts does not work

Tags: java, ms-access, diacritics, jdbc-odbc

I have MS Access database file with german umlauts in text fields. When i try to read them i have strings with ? characters instead of characters with umlauts. I try to set different characters set for database connection like *`properties.setProperty("charSet", "Cp1252");`*
but it is not work (i try cp1250, cp1251, utf8, utf16, iso-8859-1 characters sets). My system characters set is Cp1251, and when i create the MS Access database with russians characters, the russian characters imports successfully.

I found that it can be bug in the jdbc driver, but i am not sure: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6345277

If anybody knows how this problem can be solved, please tell me about.

Comment: Please specify which JDBC/ODBC bridge implementation are you using?  It is difficult to guess.

Comment: It is sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the stock Sun implementation of the jdbc-odbc connector that has been around for years.  That implementation is always described as a reference implementation and should not be used for production purposes.  I have also tried using it in the past only to find significant errors and features that are unsupported (ex: foreign keys, etc).  There are other commercial implementations that supposedly solve many of these problems.  I say supposedly as I never bought one so I cannot vouch for their functionality, but their docs indicate that they are much more complete.

Take a look [here](http://developers.sun.com/product/jdbc/drivers/search_results.jsp?jdbc_version=0&vendor_name=&cert_mode=and&jdbc_driver_type_mode=and&dbms=20&dbms_mode=and&features_mode=and&results_per_page=20&submit=Search) to see if any of the listed drivers meet your needs.

I also just found [JaySQL Lite](http://synametrics.com/SynametricsWebApp/WinSQLJdbcFeatures.jsp).  Maybe that can help you out if it meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you, but i need chargeless jdbc driver.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I had a lot of problems with that exact issue years ago, but unfortunately was unable to find anything of value.  And the Sun driver has not been maintained in several years.  I added a link of some existing jdbc-odbc drivers.  I do not know if any are FOSS or not.